# spring boot graceful shutdown - endpoint vs ConfigurableApplicationContext close method

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I was wondering if there is a deference between using the builtin endpoint for spring boot, or using the ConfigurableApplicationContext object that is returned from SpringApplication#run(String...) method?